# AngularJs how to insert one div in another?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have dynamically created a "reply comment box" (it's a directive now `<reply-comment></reply-comment>`)

```
<div class="comment-reply-wrap" ng-repeat="repUser in repUsers">
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="info" >
        <div class="left-side-info">
          <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
          <span class="name">{{repUser.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side-info">
          <p class="user-text" ng-bind-html='repUser.text'>
            <img class="comment-image" src="">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <span class="comment-email">{{repUser.email}}</span>
          <span class="comment-date">10/29/2010 at 6:40AM</span>
          <button type="submit" class="reply" ng-click="createReplyForm($event)">
            <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is top-level 'comment box'

```
<div class="comment-wrap" ng-repeat="mainComment in mainUsers">
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="info" >
        <div class="left-side-info">
          <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
          <span class="name">{{mainComment.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side-info">
          <p class="user-text" ng-bind-html='mainComment.text'>
            <img class="comment-image" src="">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <span class="comment-email">{{mainComment.email}}</span>
          <span class="comment-date">10/29/2010 at 6:40AM</span>
          <button type="submit" class="reply" ng-click="createReplyForm($event)"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cover" ng-repeat="reply in mainComment">
      <reply-comment></reply-comment>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('commentsApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('UserController', function($scope){

$scope.mainUsers = [];
$scope.repUsers = [];
$scope.bool = false;

$scope.addUser = function() {

//Dynamically create array of objects and push data

$scope.mainUsers.push({
  name: $scope.user.name,
  email: $scope.user.email,
  homepage: $scope.user.hompage,
  text: $scope.user.text
});

//Clear input fields in main form
$scope.user.name = '';
$scope.user.email = '';
$scope.user.homepage = '';
$scope.user.text = '';
};

$scope.addRepUser = function() {
 $scope.bool = false;
 //Dynamically create array of objects and push data

  $scope.repUsers.push({
  name: $scope.repUser.name,
  email: $scope.repUser.email,
  text: $scope.repUser.text
  });



 //Clear input fields in main form
 $scope.repUser.name = '';
 $scope.repUser.email = '';
 $scope.repUser.text = '';

 };

 $scope.createReplyForm = function($event) {
 $event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

 $scope.bool = true;
}

})
```

I want to insert "replied comment" into wrap of "comment" on which i am replying to, because i want to chain these "comments". The aim is to create cascade commentaries.

To make this question clearer, check this  picture of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Create a [template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create nesting directives of the same directive.

So you can make this comment item you have into a directive and then call it on itself. Example:

```
<div class="comment-reply-wrap" ng-repeat="repUser in repUsers">
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="info" >
        <div class="left-side-info">
          <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
          <span class="name">{{repUser.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side-info">
          <p class="user-text" ng-bind-html='repUser.text'>
            <img class="comment-image" src="">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <span class="comment-email">{{repUser.email}}</span>
          <span class="comment-date">10/29/2010 at 6:40AM</span>
          <button type="submit" class="reply" ng-click="createReplyForm($event)">
            <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reply">
        <my-comment-directive ng-repeat="reply in comment.replies"  comment="reply"></my-comment-directive>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So after seeing your data structures, I see a change you will need to make.  You want to iterate over comments, not over users.

Something like this

```
var commentsArray = [{text: 'comment 1', author: user1, replies: []}]
```

Where replies are simply an array of the same type of format comments.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or where I can be more clear.

Comment: You mean create custom directive of reply-comment and then insert this directive into wrap?

Comment: Yes exactly. Let it take in a comment object and then it can create its own nested views!

Comment: And one more question. What does the <div class=''reply> means in this situation? I thought tha custom directives should add like <custom-d><custom-d> or like attribute. Sorry can't understand this.

Comment: It's just a wrapper css class to easily add an indentation to non top-level comments.  Then you can add padding to that class so they slowly indent!

Comment: One more thing, is that the top level comments will also use this same directive, if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ouch, i think if i create second top-level comment it will contain in itself replied comments of the first top-level comment. Because custom directiv is nested in top-level comment div. Am i right?

Comment: No because you should have an array of comments, that each have an array of their replies, which each have their own replies etc etc.

Comment: Oh, finally. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you get it working? :) If I managed to answer your questions please be sure to vote accordingly!

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to do this now. I guess your answer is correct. But the problem is i'm really bad in Angularjs, so don't know if i can do this, heh. Anyway thank you so much

Comment: Oh ok, what are you having trouble with?  I can try to directivize it for you but not until tomorrow. But I can answer questions in the meantime.

Comment: I created directive. Insert it in the top-level comment. Then i get what i said - second top-level comment contains sub-comment of first top-level. I think it's problem in $scope or idk. Also i didn't write this `ng-repeat="reply in comment.replies"  comment="reply"` because i can't figure out where it from. I thought i have to use this instead `ng-repeat="repUser in repUsers"`

Comment: alright can you update the question with this stuff, and also add the controller and data structures?

Comment: The last clarification, if you don't mind. After sending reply it should  be pushed to `replies=[]` in the object of top level-comment. So it woulld be like this `var commentsArray = [{text: 'comment 1', author: user1, replies: [ 
{text:'reply', author:...} ]}]`?

Comment: exactly! and that comment should be able to have it's own replies as well

Comment: Thank you so much!